# getting back carriage returns after using mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: sql, mysql-real-escape-string, carriage-return

I'm finishing up on my website and want to make it very sql injection safe.  A major part of that is going through and using mysql_real_escape_string() on any potential user input.

This is fine for most things, where I simply need to use 'stripslashes' to return the original content to show on the page.  However, I cannot seem to get carriage returns back.

There are several places where users might submit pieces with carriage returns (messages are one example, starting with eg, 'Hi John,' then returning twice to the main message).  How Can I fix this?  Stripslashes just returns the message with rnrn, which is no good.

As an example (of me trying to test all possible inputs).

This text:

```
Once upon a time there was a guy named "steve" or 'john' or backslash (\)

Then, two lines later, he left.
```

Is saved like this in the SQL database:

```
Once upon a time there was a guy named \"steve\" or \'john\' or backslash (\\)\r\n\r\nThen, two lines later, he left.
```

And using stripslashes leaves it like this (note I am doing the following to print it to the html - :

```
Once upon a time there was a guy named "steve" or 'john' or backslash (\)rnrnThen, two lines later, he left.
```

I've tried nl2br, but for some reason it doesn't do anything.  Would love any thoughts here, thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps you should stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: When the database saves the slashes, your call to `mysql_real_escape_string` seems to be redundant.

Comment: @SalmanA can you elaborate on that a bit?  I'm new to coding and am not really sure how I would do that while also keeping things protected from SQL injections

Comment: @njk: this probably has something to do with magic quotes.

Comment: @cschippe: can you post a sample of how you are sanitizing and storing the data. And see if [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is on.

Comment: It's not an issue with magic quotes, as stripslashes above makes everything look correct except for the carriage returns.  It's something about the carriage returns and being able to bring those out before I do stripslashes on the front end when printing to the page

Comment: I'm doing mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["userinput"])) to put it into the database.  In this example, the database then holds:

Once upon a time there was a guy named \"steve\" or \'john\' or backslash (\\)\r\n\r\nThen, two lines later, he left.

It's not how it's saved, unless you have a better way that is safe from sql injection but also maintains returns.

Comment: Does your data literally contains `\", \', \r, \n` etc?

Comment: The original input was as described above, without any backslashes.

I escaped it to make the SQL queries safe, and doing so left it stored in the SQL database with the backslashes like `\", \', \r, \n`.  The trick now is, when I print this data the the page, to get the `\r and \n` to be the returns that they are meant to be

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things messed up.

1. mysql_real_escape_string() has nothing to do neither with sql injections nor with user input.
2. there shouldn't be unconditional stripslashes, but on purpose only.
3. When properly used, escaping is not going to database. NO ever need for stripslashes on retrieve.
4. if you have slashes in the database, you have excessive escaping. either yourcode adds slashes twice, or you're using placeholders which makes escaping useless

Comment: Okay, what would you recommend in that case?  How can I be sure SQL injections won't happen?  And how, then, can I return it back to the page?